# Ionic 2/3 in-app-browser javascript injection

Tags: html, angular, ionic2, inappbrowser

What I would like to do is open up a web page without it showing, inject javascript into it, and then proceed into my app.

The secondary page is a login page that I need to use but I don't want to show it in my app.

**Therefore, I would like to open that page, use it, and most importantly, get the login information back, all without seeing the external login page.**

I have my own login page to gather the information and a "login" button to kick it all off.

Here is what I have so far:

```
login(){
    const browser = this.iab.create('https://authn.exampleLoginPage.com/login.aspx', "_blank","hidden=yes,location=no");
    browser.executeScript({code:'document.getElementById("uxUserName").value="myUserName"'});
    browser.executeScript({code:'document.getElementById("uxPassword").value="myPassword"'})
    browser.executeScript({code:'document.getElementById("SubmitCreds").click();'})
           .then( (value) => {
                console.log("ob2 is ", value);
           })
    this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);
}
```

`login()` gets called by clicking my login button.

I am testing this in chrome by running `ionic serve` and I'm encountering a couple problems. First, the code pulls up a new tab with the external website. Second, the javascript doesn't seem to be firing. I never get to the console log in the promise. I don't know what I'm missing here.

Comment: Is there any output on the console in Chrome? Did you get a CORS error, or similar?

Comment: There are no errors, but there are warnings to which I didn't pay attention. Let me check those out and see.